# How to write a Shell script to monitor other servers' TCP connections

Tags: linux, shell, tcp, automation, monitoring

I'm seeking help to write a Shell script on Linux to monitor other servers' TCP connections. Every hour, this script will output the name list of servers whose TCP connection numbers exceed 100 into a text file. Any thoughts on this? Thanks.

Comment: You should consider using a monitoring system like Nagios for that task. In case that this would be somewhat over the top, I would make the servers collect the information themselves and deliver them to the box that needs it via ftp or sftp (scp) or similar. For counting the connections you can use "netstat -tan" in combination with "wc" and "watch", e.g.

Answer (score 1):

```
Each hour:
(can be done by a cron job)
  Log in on each server and:
  (can be done by ssh with pre-installed keys)
    list all TCP connections
    (can be done by netstat or cat /proc/net/tcp or similar)
    count them
    (can be done by wc)
```

E. g.:

```
for host in $(cat hostnames)
do
  n=$(ssh "$host" 'cat /proc/net/tcp | wc -l')
  [ "$n" -gt 100 ] && echo "$host: $n connections"
done >> logfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Dump package for specific network interface

   sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -n -q > /tmp/ccc 2>&1
2. Filter it by your favorite tool (run it each hour by cron)

   cat /tmp/ccc|sed -e 's/.*IP\ //g' -e 's/\ >.*//g'|sort|uniq
3. It's a very rough concept. In practical still need to concern many think like file retention and clean up the /tmp/ccc every hour

Comment: As for your concern on file retention, practically log file's name can be generated by time and system info. I'm just wondering how to monitor other servers using your solution.

Comment: Deploy a linux server as router, all the traffic will pass through this server. then you can sniffer all the network traffic by tcpdump

Comment: It may work, but need to put some effort to configurate network.